How to wait for webApi response with retrofit enqueue?
I use the following function to check the username and password from the web service. I want to use this function in different activities. But before I get a response from the server, the function reaches the end and returns false. Please suggest me a way to solve this issue with sample code.
public boolean checkUserPass(String username, String password) {
    userExist = false;
    UserModel user = new UserModel();
    user.setUsername(username);
    user.setPassword(password);
    Assistant.assistant.client.userCheck(user).enqueue(new Callback<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<Boolean> call, @NonNull Response<Boolean> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                userExist = response.body();
                Log.i("MyTag", response.body().toString());
            } else {
                Log.i("MyTag", "Not Success " + response);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable throwable) {
            Log.e("MyTag", "Fail");
        }
    });
    return userExist;
}

I searched all the posts but didn't get a proper answer.

The issue you're encountering is due to the asynchronous nature of the enqueue method in Retrofit. The enqueue method executes the network request on a background thread and immediately returns, while your function checkUserPass continues execution and returns false before the network request completes.
Here are the two solutions to resolve this and choose one of your needs:
1. Using a Callback Interface
Define a callback interface to handle the result of the network request and invoke the callback in the Retrofit response methods.
public interface UserCheckCallback {
    void onResult(boolean userExists);
    void onError(Throwable throwable);
}

public void checkUserPass(String username, String password, UserCheckCallback callback) {
    UserModel user = new UserModel();
    user.setUsername(username);
    user.setPassword(password);
    Assistant.assistant.client.userCheck(user).enqueue(new Callback<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<Boolean> call, @NonNull Response<Boolean> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                boolean userExist = response.body();
                Log.i("MyTag", response.body().toString());
                callback.onResult(userExist);
            } else {
                Log.i("MyTag", "Not Success " + response);
                callback.onResult(false);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Boolean> call, Throwable throwable) {
            Log.e("MyTag", "Fail", throwable);
            callback.onError(throwable);
        }
    });
}

You can then call this function and handle the result in the callback:
checkUserPass("username", "password", new UserCheckCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(boolean userExists) {
        // Handle the result here
        if (userExists) {
            // User exists
        } else {
            // User does not exist
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
        // Handle the error here
    }
});

2. Using Kotlin Coroutines (Recommended for Modern Android Development)
If you are using Kotlin, you can leverage coroutines to handle asynchronous tasks more easily.
suspend fun checkUserPass(username: String, password: String): Boolean {
    val user = UserModel(username, password)
    return try {
        val response = Assistant.assistant.client.userCheck(user).await()
        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            response.body() ?: false
        } else {
            Log.i("MyTag", "Not Success $response")
            false
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e("MyTag", "Fail", e)
        false
    }
}

You can call this function from a coroutine scope:
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
    val userExists = checkUserPass("username", "password")
    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
        if (userExists) {
            // User exists
        } else {
            // User does not exist
        }
    }
}


void enqueue(Callback<T> callback)

Asynchronously send the request and notify callback of its response or if an error occurred talking to the server, creating the request, or processing the response.

If you need to wait for the response, do not make an asynchronous call. Use instead the execute() method.

Synchronously send the request and return its response.

It seems in fact that in your case, asynchronously sending a request when you need to wait for the result is not an option. An implementation of your checkUserPass() method using execute() could look like this:
public boolean checkUserPass(String username, String password) {
    userExist = false;
    UserModel user = new UserModel();
    user.setUsername(username);
    user.setPassword(password);

    try {
        Response<Boolean> resp = Assistant.assistant.client.userCheck(user).execute();
        userExists = resp.body();
        Log.i("MyTag", resp.body().toString());
    } catch(IOException e){
        Log.e("MyTag", "Fail: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    return userExist;
}

Use enqueue when you need to perform/update something in the background according to the response received. A generic example could be the following:
// Callback implementation to asynchronously update the resource as soon as a response is received.
public class MyCallback implements Callback<MyDto> {

    private ResourceToUpdate resourceToUpdate;

    public MyCallback(ResourceToUpdate resourceToUpdate) {
        this.resourceToUpdate = resourceToUpdate;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<MyDto> call, Response<MyDto> response) {
        MyDto myDto = response.body();
        resourceToUpdate.updateWith(myDto);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<MyDto> call, Throwable throwable) {
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyCallback.class.getSimpleName());
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, throwable.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}


// Controller that asynchronously updates the resource via the custom Callback
public class MyController {

    ResourceToUpdate resourceToUpdate;
    MyApi client;
    
    public MyController(Retrofit retrofit){
        resourceToUpdate = new ResourceToUpdate();
        client = retrofit.create(MyApi.class);
    }

    public void updateResourceInTheBackground() {
        client.myRequest().enqueue(new MyCallback(resourceToUpdate));
    }
}

